# Open Modal CSS with Ajax without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a project here, in there:

I have 5 different HTML Web Form, each one already named, example (form1.html, form2.html...)

I did the Modal with CSS (demo image below), currently I open it with a HTML Anchor like "#ModalName" for example.

But, in all pages I need to put all Modal HTML inside all HTML,

I would like a help to Open my CSS Modal with Ajax, Send it with Ajax using JavaScript not jQuery and when form successfully or not comeback to the page with opened modal with the success or denied submit answer.

All example I have saw there are using jQuery and I need some Pure JavaScript.

Tks

[DEMO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo8fC.png)

Comment: do you want to draw html modal in ajax function?

Comment: And do you use bootstrap 5 on your project?

Comment: We'll need some clarification. Do you want to have the modal as an external file, and load it on button click? For example, the modal HTML is not within the HTML of your main pages. You click on a button, the modal HTML content is loaded from AJAX, and is displayed on page. Once the modal is closed, its HTML is removed from DOM. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to understand, I can give it a shot though. I don't know if this is what you mean but maybe it will help to get the ball rolling.

Lets say you build a modal

```js
function RandomId() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9)
}

function CustomModal() {

  function render(config = {}) {
    const { modalName = '' } = config
    const id = RandomId()

    const template = `
      <div class="modal ${modalName}" data-id="${id}">
        <div class="modal__content"></div>
      </div>
    `
    return { id, template }
  }


  function open(config = {}) {
    const { onRender } = config
    const _render = render(config)
    const modal_id = _render.id
    const template = _render.template

    const modal = document.querySelector(`.modal[data-id="${modal_id}"]`)
    document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template)
    if (onRender) onRender(modal)

    // now that you have a specific modal you can add event listeners to this specific one

    document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(modal => {
      if (modal.dataset.id !== modal_id) {
        /*
          Here you could remove classes or style attributes
          like opacity or transition for example. This would close
          the previous modal when a new one is opened
        */
      }
    })
  }


  function close() {
    document.querySelector('.modal').remove()
  }

  return { open, close }
}

const customModal = CustomModal()
```

Now you got a bare bones modal in vanilla js with no jquery. Here is how you could use it in your code:

```js
customModal.open({
  modalName: 'modal-1',
  onRender(modal) {
    const formContent = document.querySelector('#some-form').cloneNode(true)
    modal.querySelector('.modal-content').append(formContent)

    // here you could add in some dynamic event listeners
    // for example a form submit event
    const form = document.querySelector('#login-form')

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      fetch('/login-enpoint', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          firstName: document.querySelector('#first_name').value,
          lastName: document.querySelector('#last_name').value,
          email: // ect...
        }),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        // close your modal
        customModal.close()
      })
       
    })

  }
})
```

another thing you could do:

```js
fetch('/some-endpoint')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    customModal.open({
      onRender(modal) {
        // maybe do something with the data
      }
    })

  })
```

Comment: Hi, that's perfect, exactly what I'm looking for, I make some adjusts but it's working 100%. thanks so much.

I have only one question, in the page i have that.

<button id="openModal">One</button>
<button id="openModal">Two</button>

I need then open a different modals, and they are opening a same! :(

Comment: Good I'm glad that helped. I edited the original post, you can see now there's a data attribute in the render function and you can now target a specific modal. For your use case it might be a good example for you to look into web components.

Comment: If you have two buttons, you could attach a different event listener to each button and when each button is clicked you could pass in a different config to your modal. I also added modalName param above so you could give each one a different class name